# How should I test AKKA FSM timeouts using ScalaTest

Tags: scala, akka, scalatest

Is there an idiomatic way to test state timeouts. My actor takes a type that specifies the duration spent in different states. Some something like :

```
startWith(Off,_)    

when(Off, stateTimeout = Durations.OffDuration ) => Case Event(,_) goto(On) 

when(On, stateTimeout = Durations.OnDuration ) => Case Event(TurnOn,_) goto(Off)
```

I'd like to test that Off really does goto On and vice versa.

I could do something like :

```
val durations = new Durations(1 NanoSecond,1 Second)    
// get actor from system

thread.sleep(OffDuration) // 1 nanosecond of wait
assert(actor.StateName == On)
```

but the call to sleep feels wrong and I'm also racing against the clock by choosing "magic" duration values"

Comment: Have you've read: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.2/scala/testing.html

Comment: I have and am doing something like     actor.setState(Off,SomeData,0 nanoseconds) then assert(actor.StateName == On). But its racey as sometimes this passes and other times it fails

Comment: In the link to the docs above is the following: "awaitCond(p: => Boolean, max: Duration, interval: Duration)
Poll the given condition every interval until it returns true or the max duration is used up. The interval defaults to 100 ms and the maximum defaults to the time remaining in the innermost enclosing within block."